# Error when running a PowerShell script in VS Code that runs fine in PowerShell ISE

Tags: excel, powershell, scripting

I have a simple script that get a .csv file and manipulate it doing some changes and then save the file as an excel workbook, all works fine when I run it in PowerShell ISE but in VS Code I get the following error:

```
InvalidOperation: C:\Path\CSV Script v2.ps1:80:41
Line |
  80 |  … Objects.Add([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlListObjectSourceType]:: …
     |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Unable to find type [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlListObjectSourceType].
InvalidOperation: C:\Path\CSV Script v2.ps1:83:5
```

The error comes up when I try to do the following in the script:

```bash
 # Convert the data range to a table
$table = $worksheet.ListObjects.Add(
  [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlListObjectSourceType]::xlSrcRange, 
  $dataRange, 
  $null, 
  [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlYesNoGuess]::xlYes
)

# Name the table as the worksheet name
$table.Name = $worksheet.Name
```

I have tried multiple ways to fix the problem in VS Code but nothing seems to help and I would really like to find out why this problem is happening.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Stan

I tried to load the interop excel objects at the start of the script in many ways after finding some information in the web about that but wasn't exactly the problem I have, plus I tried many other things.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: I have tried that but then I get the error: Cannot find path 'C:\Users\stanl\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll' because it does not exist. I been trying different folder paths for the DLL but none of the ones I think has the DLL worked

Comment: If you have any recommendations I can try a folder path, thanks for your help

Comment: Might be silly question: are the 2 powershell versions the same? eg both 5.1 or 7, etc?

Comment: Hi @Minkulai yes, I did notice that PS ISE uses the old version of PS 5.1 while the computer and VScode uses version 7.3 which is a separate download. I have been looking for some information about why this problem might happens but still can haven't get anywhere

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

Use the following to **load the (latest version of) the `Microsoft.Office.InterOp.Excel` assembly also in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, so that you can use types such as `[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlListObjectSourceType]` in your script:

```bash
# Uses whatever version is installed on your machine; 
# if there are multiple, it uses the latest.
Add-Type -ErrorAction Stop -LiteralPath (
    Get-ChildItem $env:WinDir\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\*\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll | 
    Sort-Object { [version] ($_.Directory.Name -replace '_.*') }
  )[-1].FullName
```

To find out the literal path - which will be version-specific - on a given machine, open a *Windows PowerShell* (`powershell.exe`) session and run:
`Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.InterOp.Excel; [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application].Assembly.Location`; for example, of Microsoft Office *2019*, this yields the following; while you *can* use this with `Add-Type -LiteralPath`, note that you'll be locking in that specific version:

```bash
# NOTE: Works with Office 2019 only.
Add-Type -LiteralPath C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll
```

Unlike in *Windows PowerShell*, in *PowerShell (Core) 7+* this assembly is neither *implicitly* loaded when you use `New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application` nor can it be discovered by *name only* with `Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.InterOp.Excel`

- Regarding the Windows PowerShell *ISE*: It [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run *PowerShell (Core) 7+*. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

**Important**:

- A `Microsoft.Office.InterOp.Excel` assembly isn't *guaranteed* to be present on a given machine.
- If it is on the machine where you're *developing* a script, your code can break on machines where it isn't.

Read on for details.

---

The type you're trying to access - `[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlYesNoGuess]` - is from the **Excel PIA (Primary Interop Assembly)**, `Microsoft.Office.InterOp.Excel`, which wraps the COM Automation types in .NET types.

Such PIAs:

- Aren't *guaranteed* to be installed on a given machine.
- Aren't strictly *necessary* for use *in PowerShell*:

  - In the *absence* of the relevant PIA, your code must avoid references to the .NET wrapper types, such as [`[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlListObjectSourceType]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xllistobjectsourcetype) and [`[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlYesNoGuess]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlyesnoguess) and use the *underlying numeric values* of these enumeration types' values, e.g., `1` in lieu of `[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlListObjectSourceType]::xlSrcRange`, and `2` in lieu of `[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlYesNoGuess]::xlNo`, per the linked documentation.

**Caveat**:

- While the use of PIAs undoubtedly makes *development* of scripts easier, including resulting in more readable code,<sup>[1]</sup> the resulting scripts can *break* on machines where the PIAs happen not to be installed.

  - PowerShell even offers a warning on an opt-in basis when creation of a COM Automation object results in *implicit* use of PIAs (in Windows PowerShell): add the [`-Strict` switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object#example-3-use-the-strict-parameter-to-generate-a-non-terminating-error) to the `New-Object -ComObject` call.
- The **upshot** is:

  - ***Either*: Develop your script *without* referencing .NET wrapper types from PIAs**, as described above, so it can run on machines without PIAs too.
  - ***Or*: Ensure that all target machines have the relevant PIAs** installed.

---

<sup>[1] Other benefits are the ability to *discover* (via [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member)) and *tab-complete* the members of the objects that make up the Excel object model.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the correct add-type command to enter and load the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll`.
Once I found the right path the fix was adding this to the beginning of the script:

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\15.0.0.0_71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll'
```